# How to get x, y, z texture coordinates in LuxCore?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-coordinates, luxrender-render-engine

I do a lot of math-based procedural texturing, and have been considering switching a few of my scenes to LuxCoreRender instead of Cycles since it seems to do a better job with reducing noise from emission materials. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the local coordinates as values to use as the starting point for my textures. In Cycles I would've just used the "texture coordinate: object" input and then plugged it into "SplitXYZ," but I'm having trouble understanding how to do that with LuxCore nodes. What should I do?